# Serialize data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, serialization

I'm looking to improve my jQuery code.

The piece of code is submitting data to another PHP page for processing.

At the moment I'm taking data submitted from a form, and taking data from a custom data attribute from the page.

Here's the code

```
// Add new comment to nit on comment.php page

$('#new_comment_form').bind('submit', function(e) {

        // Prevent default
        e.preventDefault();

        var commentNitId = $('#left_content').attr('data-nit-id');

        var commentData = 'nit_id=' + commentNitId + '&new_comment_text=' + $('textarea.new_comment').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/addComment.php",
            data: commentData, 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(comment_response) {

                // Code upon success

            },
            error: function() {
                            // Error
                alert("Error adding comment");
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm just wondering if there is a better ("neater") way to serialize the data ready to submit to the form?

Kind Regards,

Luke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If you supply an object (a standard Javascript object) to `$.ajax` as the `data` option, jQuery will handle the serialization for you.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/addComment.php",
    data: {
        nit_id: commentNitId,
        new_comment_text: $('textarea.new_comment').val()
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (comment_response) {

        // Code upon success
    },
    error: function () {
        // Error
        alert("Error adding comment");
    }
});
```

If you want to what this produces, the function used internally is `jQuery.param`.  So:

```
jQuery.param({
    nit_id: 5,
    new_comment_text: 'foobar'
});
// output: "nit_id=5&new_comment_text=foobar"
```

Note that this has the added bonus of escaping characters where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at jquery serialize() and serializeArray() functions. They provide a neat way to get form data.

Comment: Hi Pipalayan, I have explored these functions, however my complication comes when it comes to producing a serialized array based on the form elements and the data attributes.  How do I merge the two?  Thanks again!

Comment: @LukeCoulton Unfortunately there is no straightforward way to get a serialized array based on data attributes {serializeArray() gives you array based on "name" attribute}. For any other custom attribute, you would have to iterate the form elements and find your values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type:'post', 
            url: "ajax/addComment.php",
            data:$(this).parents('form:first').serialize(),
                            success: function (comment_response) {

                                     // Code upon success
                                 },
                            error: function () {
                                       // Error
                                alert("Error adding comment");
                             },
        });
```